# Hazelcast NPE after adding server jcache bean

Tags: hazelcast

I'm getting an exception as seen in : https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10328

Using Hazelcast: 3.9.1 and Jet: 0.5.1

This began after adding a cluster embedded jcache bean to a cluster that has clients also using the same cache with near caches.

```
2018-02-28 15:52:01,904 [hz.ttcore.event-3] ERROR c.h.s.i.e.i.EventServiceImpl - [192.168.70.25]:18320 [ttcore] [0.5.1] hz.ttcore.event-3 caught an exception while processing task:com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.LocalEventDispatcher@74e130af
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.util.ParameterUtil.calculateDataSize(ParameterUtil.java:32) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.codec.CacheAddNearCacheInvalidationListenerCodec.encodeCacheBatchInvalidationEvent(CacheAddNearCacheInvalidationListenerCodec.java:169) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.cache.CacheAddNearCacheInvalidationListenerTask$NearCacheInvalidationListener.encodeBatchInvalidation(CacheAddNearCacheInvalidationListenerTask.java:63) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.invalidation.AbstractBaseNearCacheInvalidationListener.sendInvalidation(AbstractBaseNearCacheInvalidationListener.java:54) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.cache.AbstractCacheClientNearCacheInvalidationListener.handleEvent(AbstractCacheClientNearCacheInvalidationListener.java:47) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractCacheService.dispatchEvent(AbstractCacheService.java:460) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractCacheService.dispatchEvent(AbstractCacheService.java:70) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.LocalEventDispatcher.run(LocalEventDispatcher.java:64) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.process(StripedExecutor.java:225) [hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:208) [hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
```

Note: I did try 3.9.3 and same behavior.

Comment: This looks like an issue, could you please add a comment to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10328 with the exception and any useful information for reproducing it? Thanks!

Comment: I've added a comment to that ticket, but that ticket is closed? Please advise if that is ok.

Comment: Thanks, reopened the issue based on your report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted details to hazelcast issue ticket as requested by hazelcast engineers.